# my JFrame has a error "Cannot instantiate the type JFrame" and no research has come with a product

Tags: java, eclipse

```java
package dragon.io.display;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

    private frame;

    private String title;
    private int width, height;

    public Display(String title, int width, int height){
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        creatDisplay();

    }

    private void creatDisplay(){
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setlocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

here is my code but am externally confused

Comment: It would help to actually declare a JFrame field...

Comment: `private frame;` is not valid Java

Comment: ok i just applied those comments but that fixed a different problem not this one

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: 1) You have no main method to start the application.  2) Your class variable is "private JFrame frame;".